# How to access model from controller?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I can't seem to get the model from inside the controller, even though the controller seems to have a model property set.  The following:

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        console.log(this.get('model'));
        console.log(this.model);
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

prints out:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide the code for your related route please?

Comment: @JellyFishBoy It's all sorted now, so I won't bother chucking my route in.  Thanks for the comment though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The an `Ember.ObjectController` is a proxy for the model. So the model can be referenced using `this` as you found in your example. So then in a template `{{this.aModelAttr}}` or just {{aModelAttr}}. Like you question suggests it's a bit confusing.

The `ObjectController` is being deprecated as of Ember 1.11.0. So to simplify use `Ember.Controller` and in your controller you can reference the model by `this.get('model')`

Then in the template use `{{model.aModelAttr}}`

To give the `model` a domain specific ie: books or user name use

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    domainSpecificName: Ember.computed.alias('model')
}
```

Then in your templates you can use `{{domainSpecificName.aModelAttr}}`

Comment: Awesome, I'll give this a go first thing in the morning!

Comment: So it looks like my problem was something else (see my answer below), but I'll accept this because it cleared things up for me and pointed me in the right direction.  Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 4):

So it turns out that when I examine the model by setting a break point it is empty.  I assume the console shows content because it updates the model once the content arrives.

In `init()` the model is unreachable:

```
init: function() {
    this._super();
    console.log(this.get('model'));  // null
}
```

Same for any method `.on('init')`:

```
onInit: function() {
    console.log(this.get('model'));  // null
}.on('init'),
```

But the model is accessible to actions (I'm assuming because the model has been set up by the time the action is called):

```
someAction: function() {
    console.log(this.get('model'));  // model object as expected
}
```

So to answer my question, `this.get('model')` can be used to access the model from the controller, but just not in `init()` or `.on('init')` methods.